# В каком предложении допущена пунктуационная ошибка ?

Tags: пунктуация

1) Месяц совсем закатился, ледяная равнина потемнела.
2) Погода была неблагоприятная: моросил нудный осенний дождь и дул сильный ветер.
3) Игнат спустил курок-ружьё дало осечку.
4) В июльские дни краски светлы, но не ярки, на всём лежит печать какой-то нежности.

Answer (score 5):

Екатерина, Вы ошибаетесь насчет второго предложения. Запятая не ставится,  если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют  общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения. Ответа не вижу. Разве что действительно путаница  дефис - тире, но никогда не видела, чтобы это проверяли. Или спрашивающий где-то ошибся при наборе.

Пример из Лопатина:

Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится

[link 
text](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

**Дополняю еще раз.**

**У Розенталя:** [здесь](http://lib.rus.ec/b/118184/read)(Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация.)

**Цитирую:**

РАЗДЕЛ 9 Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении
§ 30. Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении

1. Запятая перед союзами и, да («и»), или, либо не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения **объединены каким-либо общим для них элементом.**

Далее читаем **в примечании:** 3) **Общим может быть поясняемое двумя частями сложносочиненного предложения третье предложение, предшествующее им и связанное с ними бессоюзной связью:** Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М.Г.); Он чувствовал себя нехорошо: тело было слабо и в глазах ощущалась тупая боль (Купр.); Одно было ясно: ссора оказалась окончательной и назад он не вернётся; Это похоже на то, что мы наблюдаем в кожных покровах: при каждом нашем движении одежда стирает мёртвые клетки поверхностного слоя и их заменяют нижележащие клетки.

**У Лопатина** [здесь](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133) 
**Цитирую:**:

В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо **запятая не ставится** в следующих случаях:

2) если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово, общий обособленный член или **общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения**: Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить; Вопреки предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал; Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится (Щерб.); Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой (Пауст.);

ПОдобное есть и у Валгиной, у Николенковой, на сайтах для учеников, но я думаю, цитаты из Розенталя достаточно, чтобы убедить сомневающихся в том, что это не новации Лопатина. Принцип здесь один - есть объединяющий элемент для частей СПП - запятая не ставится. Части СПП становятся похожи на однородные  члены. И пунктуация - как при однородных членах.

Надеюсь, сейчас достаточно подробно  и понятно.

Answer (score 2):

Убрала часть ответа. Копирую свой же комментарий.

У Тургенева в 4 предложении стоит ТОЧКА С ЗАПЯТОЙ после слова НЕ ЯРКИ. Я тоже хотела этот знак поставить. Но грубая ли это ошибка - запятая вместо точки с запятой?

***Игнат спустил курок - ружьё дало осечку.*** Заменять в этом БСП тире  на двоеточие нельзя, так как второе предложение имеет значение противопоставления (или быстрой смены событий). Только тире. Ср.:***Игнат спустил курок, но ружьё дало осечку.***

Comment: У меня под рукой сейчас нет вообще ни одного справочника, но помнится, что где-то было именно так, как у Екатерины: правило насчет общей поясняемой части актуально только для придаточных сложноподчиненного.  Может попутал - может времена изменились.

Comment: Лара, здравствуйте. Я думала над тем, что Вы говорите, прежде чем ответить на вопрос. Главное предложение при однородных придаточных действительно является условием, при котором запятую не ставим. Но здесь бессоюзие. Давайте вместе найдём подтверждение Вашей правоты, для всех это важно, особенно для меня. Спасибо!
У Тургенева в 4 предложении стоит ТОЧКА С ЗАПЯТОЙ после слова НЕ ЯРКИ. Я тоже хотела этот знак поставить. Но грубая ли это ошибка - запятая вместо точки с запятой?

Comment: Ну например в справочнике Лопатина. Да и у Розенталя должно быть. Вообще здесь принцип один - есть объединяющий элемент, запятая не ставится. Ссылку добавлю в ответ. 

Про точку с запятой  тоже думала. Обычно это не считается за ошибку.

Comment: Да, есть у Лопатина. Молодчина, Лара! Вывод: всё дело в точке с запятой.

Comment: А где и что именно у него есть? Если не секрет?

Comment: Читайте ответ. Он сначала был комментарием, поэтому, наверное, непонятно.

Comment: Отнюдь. Я вообще-то попросил сформулировать, что там такого интересного у Лопатина или дать конкретную ссылку.  

Кстати, не поясните, что такое "общую придаточную часть" в сложносочиненном предложении?    

Короче, очередная новация Лопатина...

Comment: Никаких в данном случае новаций. Речь идет о предложениях с разными видами связи.

Answer (score 0):

> Игнат спустил курок-ружьё дало осечку.

Тут дефис или тире? Тире возможно, дефис - нет.

//-----------------------------

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f) Вот все, из Лопатина со страницы, на которую Вы дали ссылку.
Где здесь фраза, что в сложносочиненном предложении запятая опускается в случае, если используется двоеточие?
//=======

§ 112. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится запятая.

При этом между ними устанавливаются отношения соединительные (союзы и, да в значении «и», ни...ни), противительные (союзы а, но, да в значении «но», однако, же, зато, а то, впрочем), разделительные (союзы или, либо, ли... или, ли... ли, то ли... то ли, то... то, не то... не то), присоединительные (союзы да и, и притом, также, тоже, значит) и пояснительные (союзы а именно, то есть, или в значении «то есть»):

а) Повествование у меня получается строго документальным, и дальше я должен идти избранной стезей (Чив.); И вновь одиноко заблещет вода, и глянет ей в око ночная звезда (Забол.); Ни солнца мне не виден свет, ни для корней моих простору нет, ни ветеркам вокруг меня свободы (Крыл.);

б) Мать ехала с отцом со станции Сиверской, а мы, дети, выехали им навстречу (Наб.); В окнах дома блестел ленинградский слепой свет, но для нас обоих и это место и этот свет казались священными (Пауст.); Дорого, зато хорошая вещь; Антон Семенович, разрешите проводить девчат из Пироговки, а то они боятся (Мак.); Товарищи относились к нему неприязненно, солдаты же любили воистину (Купр.); Все ребята хотели тебя здесь дожидаться, да я отговорил (Фад.); В этом году ему не удалось поступить в институт, впрочем все еще было впереди;

в) Слышался ли в открытые окна трезвон городских и монастырских колоколов, кричал ли на дворе павлин, или кашлял кто-нибудь в передней, всем невольно приходило на мысль, что Михаил Ильич серьезно болен (Ч.); Блеснет ли день за синею горою, взойдет ли ночь с осеннею луною, я все тебя, далекий друг, ищу (П.); Не то дождь моросит, не то снежная крупа сыплется; То ли не нравится работа машинистки, то ли не понравился этот Филимонов (Сим.); То он собирался поступить в зоологический сад учиться на укротителя львов, то его тянуло к пожарному делу (Кав.);

г) Мне вздумалось завернуть под навес, где стояли наши лошади, посмотреть, есть ли у них корм; и притом осторожность никогда не мешает (Л.); Я собралась уезжать, брат тоже складывал вещи; От тепла и сырости его клонило в сон, да он и не старался противиться (Сим.); Тучи надвигаются, значит будет дождь;

д) Нужно добывать именно хлеб, то есть нужно пахать, сеять, косить, молотить (Ч.); Отец всегда старался занять детей интересным делом, а именно он покупал новые книги, придумывал забавные игры.

Примечание. Союзы ли... или в сложносочиненном предложении относятся к повторяющимся союзам. Это же сочетание союзов может использоваться и в предложении со сказуемыми, отнесенными к общему подлежащему, тогда запятая перед или не ставится. Ср.: Судьба ли нас свела опять на Кавказе, или она нарочно сюда приехала, зная, что меня встретит (Л.). — Видит ли он это или не видит — не столь важно.

В сложносочиненном предложении с одиночными союзами и, да (в значении «и»), или, либо запятая не ставится в следующих случаях:

1) если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общий второстепенный член или общую придаточную часть: В ветер леса шумят великим океанским гулом и вершины сосен гнутся вслед пролетающим облакам (Пауст.); Сквозь дождь лучилось солнце и раскидывалась радуга от края до края (Пришв.); К полудню черные облака почти коснутся земли, задует сырой ветер и польются томительные, нагоняющие сон обложные дожди (Пауст.); Когда взошло солнце, роса высохла и трава позеленела; если же придаточная часть относится только к одной из частей сложносочиненного предложения, то вторая часть его отделяется запятой: Когда я крепко двинул лыжи под гору, облако холодной снежной пыли взвилось мне навстречу, и по всему девственно-белому, пушистому косогору правильно и красиво прорезались два параллельных следа;

2) если части сложносочиненного предложения имеют общее вводное слово, общий обособленный член или общую, поясняемую ими, часть сложного предложения: Словом, время уже истекло и пора было уходить; Вопреки предсказаниям синоптиков, небо уже прояснилось и дождь перестал; Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится (Щерб.); Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой (Пауст.);

3) если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой номинативные предложения: Слышишь? Хриплый стон и скрежет ярый! (П.); однако если номинативных предложений больше, чем два, и союз и повторяется, то запятые ставятся — по правилу, которое действует при выделении однородных членов предложения (см. § 26): Шипенье подводного песка, неловкого краба ход, и чаек полет, и пробег бычка, и круглой медузы лед (Багр.); И голубой дымок, и первых встреч неясная тревога, и на плечи наброшенный платок, казенный дом и дальняя дорога (Сим.) (в последней части — казенный дом и дальняя дорога — запятой нет, так как эта часть воспринимается как единое целое; повторение союза и прервалось перед частью казенный дом);

4) если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой безличные или неопределенно-личные предложения с одинаковой формой сказуемого: С деревьев капало и вокруг пахло листвой; Зрителей разместили вокруг арены и на арену вывели участников представления;

5) если части сложносочиненного предложения представляют собой побудительные, вопросительные или восклицательные предложения; объединяющей здесь оказывается интонация, а в побудительных предложениях могут быть и общие частицы: Где будет собрание и кто его председатель? — общая вопросительная интонация; Как тихо вокруг и как чисто звездное небо! — общая восклицательная интонация; Пусть светит солнце и птицы поют! — общая частица.

§ 113. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять точка с запятой, особенно если его части значительно распространены и имеют внутри запятые (чаще при наличии союзов а, но, зато, же, тоже, также): Ужас сердце чует в этот краткий миг, который делит гул громовый на удары; а они гремят, и тучи разрываются, бросая золотые стрелы молний из рядов своих на землю (М. Г.); Мне это показалось парадоксом, и не сразу я понял смысл его слов; но он такой: за Кильдинским королем культурная страна... (Пришв.); Я схватил его за руку; но он тихо и гордо посмотрел на меня (Дост.); — Мы рассуждаем серьезно; а не хотите меня удостоить вашим вниманием, так ведь кланяться не буду (Дост.); — Вот твое жалованье; видишь, я выдаю; но зато ты должен спасти меня (Дост.); ...В прошлый раз ездил к танкистам днем; ночью же все казалось другим, незнакомым (Каз.); Некоторое время сквозь эту пелену еще доносился шум лиственниц, потом смолк и он, как будто задавленный густым снегом; ветер тоже стихал (Кор.).

§ 114. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится тире, если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение результата, следствия, резкого противопоставления (чаще перед союзом и, реже перед союзами но, а): Надо успеть записать. Малейшая задержка
— и мысль, блеснув, исчезнет (Пауст.); Сначала я старался не зачерпнуть воды или грязи в туфли, но оступился раз, оступился другой — и стало всё равно (Сол.); Он делал вид, что слушает хозяйку, изумлялся самым простым вещам, хлопал себя по колену — и опять говорил только о себе (Бун.); По дубу перейдем ручей — и на болото (Пришв.); Положишь палочку на воду — и она поплывет по течению (Пришв.); Она вдохнула в себя немного воздуху — и запахло холодным морем (Улиц.); Душа, как прежде, каждый час полна томительною думой — но огнь поэзии погас (П.); Я спешу туда ж — а там уже весь город (П.).

Примечание. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять запятая и тире как единый знак препинания: Оскалив зубы, староста стал драть его кнутом по чем попало, — и от боли и от ужаса Аверкий проснулся весь в слезах (Бун.); На очереди были полицейские пункты, — и там о Давиде никто ничего не слыхал (Пришв.). Такое разделение частей сложносочиненного предложения несколько устарело.

Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания следует отличать от сочетания запятой и тире, когда каждый знак стоит на собственном основании: Кто знает, сколько придется пробыть в тайге, — и все время будет за спиной Гринька и его товарищи (Шукш.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть предложения, а тире разделяет части сложносочиненного предложения.

//----------------

Comment: дефис...сегодня на экзамене по русскому языку,набрал 60 баллов всего лишь, а мог и больше 70 ))) всех благодарю за помощь!!!

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно пункт 2.

Comment: @Ларf, я не за бегемотуса, но тоже хочу более содержательных комментариев. Читают-то люди разные, не все способны сами разобраться по таким указаниям.  
    
@behemothus, у Вас в чем сомнения? Тут вроде говорят о том, что все предложение - бессоюзное сложноподчиненное. И в нем два придаточных, соединенных союзои И.

Comment: Ирина!
~1. Сомнения в трактовке и применимости правила.  
~2. "бессоюзное сложноподчиненное" - это не из современной грамматики. Вы видимо имели в виду сложносочиненное - одновременно и одновременно глваное в сложноподчиненном - с одной на оба главных подчиненной часть. Здесь (у Лопатина) речь скорее всего о нем.Только формулировка туманна.  
~3. Тут все запутали окончательно, что немудрено, когда дают некомментированную ссылку - и не отвечают на вопросы. Ничего личного ни к кому.
~4. Сказанное у меня в ~2. ничего общего с разбираемым, имхо, не имеет.

Comment: ~5. По сути. У Розенталя подобный случай, насколько могу судить, этот случай не описан. Посему - скорее всего именно **новация** Лопатина. А формулировка - сомнительная, поэтому остаются вопросы. Сам же мой вопрос объясняется тем, что очень сложно сказать, под какой из перечисленных случаев подходит каждый из примеров. там бабка надвое сказала. А значит и обобщение на нащ случай явно преждевременно.

Comment: ~6. Топикстартер потерял интерес к теме, насколько могу судить, дав разъяснение, что ошибка - в дефисе вместо тире. Хотя наверняка это только сам он и знает.  
~7. Продолжать выяснять, кто что сказал - и зачем, у меня более нет ни сил, ни желания. В том, что тут не нужна запятая не сомневаюсь, в том что об этом речь у Лопатина (именно там, куда меня ткнули носом) - сомневаюсь крепко.

Comment: Еще раз добавила в ответ.